Usage of the preposition On
I have a question about using the preposition 'on'. For a few times, I have noticed it used in the following context:

Oh, the language on you! - (from the Sopranos).

Luck on that Silvio (from the Sopranos).

The man`s got a brain on him.

Wow! The balls on this guy. Respect!

The power on this car! - (Counting Cars-FB page, video - Top 5 mind-blowing
cars).


Is this accepted usage of the preposition 'on' in both BrE and AmE?

Can you indicate what research you've done and how much you already know. I've no idea if you are aware that "the balls on this guy" refers literally to testicles, and "on" is used for external bodily features and other things stuck or fastened to something.

@StuartF "The balls on this guy" doesn`t refer to his testicles but his bravery in a given, particular situation.

Yes, the "the language on you!" is odd, but figurative, like "The mouth on you!" "Faux modesty is not a good color on you." Brilliant dialogue not recommended as a model of language to copy.

It's the appendage metaphor. Treating a non-physical attribute (idiolect, courage/tenacity, insolence/vulgarity ['mouth']) ...  as a physical one. The metaphor may consist merely of the choice of 'on', or may be extended (balls, mouth ...).

@Lambie It can also mean that they use profanity a lot. That's probably how it was meant in the Sopranos.
